# Hyper V VM's on Windows 2012 host have no web access

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012

Using the Hyper V role in Server 2012 to create Windows 2008 R2 VM. Host has one NIC.

Virtual Switch was set up as below:

- set as external network
- 'allow management OS' was checked.
- switch was selected as the network adapter for the VM

At this point the host has web access (this is never an issue).

VM is launched but doesn't have web access. Network and sharing center in VM says it is connected to an 'unidentified network' (private network). Network discovery is on.

I have already switched the NIC on the host machine - that didn't help.

What am I missing?

Additional 01: 
I just created a VM running Win7x64 OS. Same problem.

Additional 02: 
I thought that maybe I had a bad install of Server 2012 so I put a new (C) drive in and installed the OS again. Did the windows updates and created a new VM by connecting to an existing VHDX file. Same problem as before.

Additional 03: 
I have not made any changes to the VM network connection. 
IP and DNS is still set to automatic. 
Below is a link to images of IPCONFIG of host and VM.
On top is ipconfig of host. 
Bottom is the VM.

http://i593.photobucket.com/albums/tt16/Varminter556/ipconfigs_zps1afdedaa.jpg

FIXED THE PROBLEM:
Please unlock thread so I can share.

Comment: Start with the basics. Does the VM have a valid ip address configuration?

Comment: The links to the images are broken.

Comment: Do you have a DHCP server running on your network?  Do you have a valid scope setup?  If you statically setup an IP in the VM can you ping anything?  Can we get a screenshot of the configuration of your virtual switch perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

OK, based on the image I'd say that you're probably new at this. The VM has an [APIPA](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/APIPA.html) ip address. Without going into a long explanation I'll simply tell you that the VM `does not` have a valid ip address. (an APIPA ip address is valid in very specific scenarios, but not yours). You need to either assign a valid static ip address to the VM's or you need to implement a DHCP server and configure it accordingly so that the VM's are given appropriate ip address settings.